# How to access Page classes and Usercontrols in code files for website projects

Tags: asp.net, webforms, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to convert an ASP.net web application into a website. One issue i am coming across is trying to access usercontrols and masterpages in my code files.

The code below shows a class i am using for a base class, it inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.

```
public class AdminBase : BasePage
{
    DeniedAccess deniedAccessControl;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        //All pages that inherit from this will have a denied access control which will display when an admin of one instance tries to access admin pages of a different instance 
        //which they don't have access to. This enables us to still use the built in web.config authroisation API 

        deniedAccessControl = (DeniedAccess)Page.LoadControl("~/App_Controls/DeniedAccess.ascx");

       ((MasterPage1)Master).MainContent.Controls.Add(deniedAccessControl);

    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        if (deniedAccessControl.ContentVisible)
        {
            foreach (Control control in ((MasterPage1)Master).MainContent.Controls)
            {
                //only sets to false if the control is set to true as it will error if you try to set a non visiual controls "Visible" property. E.g an sqldatasource control
                if (control.GetType() != deniedAccessControl.GetType() && control.Visible)
                      control.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The "DeniedAccess" control is a user control i am dynamically adding if the user fails some custom authorization.

This worked fine when this was a web application as the DeniedAccess control was compiled into the same dll so i could access it from the code. Now that it is a website it cannot find the namespace/class as it is not in the App_Code folder.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in a website project? I can't seem to find a way and the only alternative i see is having to write this code for each individual page rather than use it on a base page.

I also get the same problem when trying to cast the master page to my "MasterPage1" class for the same reason, it can't find it so i cannot access it's properties.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade from ***Web Application Project*** to ***Website Project***?

Comment: We want to convert it to a web site project so when we update the system we can only update one code file not the entire dll. So if we are working on an update but we have to update some code to fix a bug, it is a lot easier to just update one file than rolling back all the code.

Comment: Website Project has been deprecated long time ago, because it created a lot of problems. You need to find an alternative approach to update your site.

Comment: I have no idea why you think it is _easier_ to just update one code file. Look into the web publishing capability of Visual Studio. It's capable of just publishing the files that changed (including the web application DLL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating two interfaces to solve this problem, as it wasn't a code behind file i couldn't just add a reference to the control/master page in the source.

I made my usercontrol inherit this interface

```
public interface IDeniedAccessControl 
{
   bool ContentVisible
   {
       get;
   }
}
```

And my master page inherit this one

```
public interface IMasterPage
{
   void AddControl(Control control);

   ControlCollection MainContentControls
   {
       get;
   }
}
```

I then made my usercontrol and master page implement there respective interface with the desired functionality.

Master page implementation:

```
    public void AddControl(Control control)
    {
       ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
    }


   public ControlCollection MainContentControls
   {
       get { return ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls; }
   }
```

User control implementation:

```
        bool IDeniedAccessControl.ContentVisible
        {
           get { return ContentASPxPanel.Visible; }
        }
```

I could then use this on any code file. Below is how i edited my original code.

```
    public class AdminBase : BasePage
    {
    IDeniedAccessControl deniedAccessControl;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        //All pages that inherit from this will have a denied access control which will display when an admin of one instance tries to access admin pages of a different instance 
        //which they don't have access to. This enables us to still use the built in web.config authroisation API 
        deniedAccessControl = (IDeniedAccessControl)Page.LoadControl("~/App_Controls/DeniedAccess.ascx");

       ((IMasterPage)Master).AddControl((Control)deniedAccessControl);

    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        if (deniedAccessControl.ContentVisible)
        {
            foreach (Control control in ((IMasterPage)Master).MainContentControls)
            {
                //only sets to false if the control is set to true as it will error if you try to set a non visiual controls "Visible" property. E.g an sqldatasource control
                if (control.GetType() != deniedAccessControl.GetType() && control.Visible)
                    control.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```